# How to generate 1-10 3 times by lodash one line

Tags: javascript, random, lodash

I try to use this expression to do it.

`_.times(3, _.random(1, 10))`

but return this:

`[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

my expect result like this:

```
[3, 7, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the random call in a callback, because [`_.times`](https://lodash.com/docs/#times) expects an iteratee. That is a number your case and that results to `undefined`.

```js
console.log(_.random(1, 10));                  // number, not a function
console.log(_.times(3, 42));                   // call with a number
console.log(_.times(3, i => _.random(1, 10))); // call with function
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just note, this won't produce uniq numbers ... you can get 3 times `9`

Comment: @RickyLevi, that's random ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to do it for 3 values -

```
var nums[3];

for(var x = 0;x<3;x++){num[x] = random(1,10);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.map(new Array(3),() => _.random(1,10))
```

This works because the Array constructor considers an integer as the sole argument as an arrayLength.

Since we now have an array with a length of 3, we can use `map` with it to return a new array of the same length, but with each value generated from the return value of a function.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).